# Laravel 5.4 edit post isnt working

Tags: php, laravel, edit

Im new in Laravel and i dont understand how to make action forms and routing for editing post

Here is my routes --

```
    Route::post('/menu', 'MenuController@store');

    Route::resource('/menu', 'MenuController');
```

here is controller --

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'menuName' => 'required',
        'menuLink' => 'required'
    ]); 

    //create new menu

    return $id; 



   //   $menus->name = $request->input('menuName');
    //$menus->link = $request->input('menuLink');
    //$menus->save();

    //return redirect('/menu')->with('success', 'Menu updated');
}
```

Return $id is for check what "id" will give me and he gives me this- "{id}"

here is form --

```
    <form action = "/menu/{id}" method = "POST"> 
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name = "_method" type = "hidden" value = "PUT">
                <input type="text" id="menuName" name="menuName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu name">
                <input type="text" id="linkName" name="menuLink" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu link ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

i am really messed up allready and dont know what i am doing wrong. I cant understand why update funtion returns me "{id}" not value of ID and how can i make this all works

Comment: I dont know what templating engine you are using and where you generate your html. However, in blade (and a lot of other engines) you put your variables between double handlebars. So: action="/menu/{{id}}"

Comment: I write pure html and after action="/menu/{{id}}" i got error - Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (View: /var/www/vhosts/pokkers.lv/goartandcraft.com/laravel/resources/views/admin/editmenu.blade.php)

Comment: There is something quite wrong with your code, I don't know why `$id` doesn't exist where you form is.

Answer (score 0):

Your are not passing id in your view , you are passing it as a string , u need it create a variable and set it to the right id and pass it to your form.

Change your form action from
`action = "/menu/{id}"`

to

```
action = "/menu/".$id"
```

or you can use laravel blade

```
Form::open(['route' => ['menu.update', $id]])
```

and don't forget to close the form at the end

```
 {!!Form::close!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did something wrong with the `action` attribute. Change it to:
`action="/menu/{{ $id }}"`

Comment: Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (View: /var/www/vhosts/pokkers.lv/goartandcraft.com/laravel/resources/views/admin/editmenu.blade.php)

Comment: @KarlisPokkers Sorry, I meant `{{ $id }}`. That's why you're getting that error.

Comment: Undefined variable: id (View: /var/www/vhosts/pokkers.lv/goartandcraft.com/laravel/resources/views/admin/editmenu.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

you have an edit method which will show the form, that method should return the menu object

```
public function update($id)
{
     // get the menu you wan to edit
    $menu = Menu::find($id);
     // return the form with the menu object
    return view('your.form.view', compact('menu'));
}
```

Now the form should be like this

```
// use that object u returned in the form action
<form action = "/menu/{{ $menu->id }}" method = "POST"> 
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input name = "_method" type = "hidden" value = "PUT">
    <input type="text" id="menuName" name="menuName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu name">
    <input type="text" id="linkName" name="menuLink" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu link ">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now the update method should be something like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'menuName' => 'required',
        'menuLink' => 'required'
    ]); 
 // update the data
  $bool = Menu::where('id',$id)->update([
     'menuName'=> $request->menuName,
     'menuLink'=> $request->menuLink,
   ]);
   if(!$bool){
    Session::flash('alert','error');
    return view('page.index');
    }
    Session::flash('alert','success');
    return view('page.index');
}
```

This first method is "get" edit that should show the form,
the second is put update that should receive the data from the form(after the show method) and use i to update.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error  ---

in update blade befor form i added foreach

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">  
    @foreach($menus as $menus)
        <form action="/menu/{{$menus->id}}" method="POST">
        @endforeach
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name = "_method" type = "hidden" value = "PUT">
                <input type="text" id="menuName" name="menuName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu name">
                <input type="text" id="linkName" name="menuLink" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu link ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

But now he is editing only 1st post and no matter wich post edit im switching

here is controller --

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    $menus = Menu::all();
    return view('admin.editmenu')->with('menus', $menus);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'menuName' => 'required',
        'menuLink' => 'required'
    ]); 

    //create new menu

    $menus = Menu::find($id); 

    $menus->name = $request->input('menuName');
    $menus->link = $request->input('menuLink');
    $menus->save();

    return redirect('/menu')->with('success', 'Menu updated');
}
```

menu list blade ---

```
    @if(count($menus) > 1)
            @foreach($menus as $menus)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>{{$menus->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$menus->link}}</td>
                    <td>{{$menus->created_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{$menus->updated_at}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type = "button"class = "btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                        <a href = "/menu/{{$menus->id}}/edit" class = "btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            @else
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ive got it and resolved.

I will start with routes

routes----------

```
    Route::resource('menu', 'MenuController');
```

that post route was unnecessary, but that didnt affect anything

controller -------

```
     public function edit($id)
{
    $menus = Menu::find($id);
    return view('admin.editmenu')->with('menus', $menus);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'menuName' => 'required',
        'menuLink' => 'required'
    ]); 

    //create new menu

    $menus = Menu::find($id); 

    $menus->name = $request->input('menuName');
    $menus->link = $request->input('menuLink');
    $menus->save();

    return redirect('/menu')->with('success', 'Menu updated');
}
```

Where in edit function i must find ID witch needs to be editing

menu list -----------------

```
    @if(count($menus) > 1)
            @foreach($menus as $menu)
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>{{$menu->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$menu->link}}</td>
                    <td>{{$menu->created_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{$menu->updated_at}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type = "button"class = "btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                        <a href = "/menu/{{$menu->id}}/edit" class = "btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            @else
            <p class = "well"> No menu items created!</p>
            @endif
```

I only changed $menus as $menus on "$menus as $menu" to be clear.

edit blade ------------

```
    @extends('admin.main')

    @section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  

        <form action="/menu/{{$menus->id}}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name = "_method" type = "hidden" value = "PUT">
                <input type="text" id="menuName" name="menuName" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu name" value="{{ $menus->name }}">
                <input type="text" id="linkName" name="menuLink" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Menu link " value="{{ $menus->link }}">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

    @endsection
```

Here i deleted @foreach like @Snapey told and added the value option.
I guess value option gave me the errrors all the time.

Thank you all for attention and willing to help! Hope that someday i could help others with my knowledge.